# JAVA implementation of NMI Payment gateway

Tags: payment-gateway

I am integrating NMI payment gateway with my JAVA Project. I am new to payment gateways and am looking for it's JAVA implementation. It's Dev Docs are helpful but can't find a JAVA example for the same.
If anyone has any reference to a site/document where I can find its JAVA implementation it will be a great help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try out this link? Please take a look at this:

https://secure.networkmerchants.com/gw/merchants/resources/integration/integration_portal.php#mobile_methodology